# what is the best way to keep session alive?

Tags: asp.net

I have written a Javascript control that pops up on a page a minute before the user's session is about to expire. If the user clicks a button on the control, the session is kept alive.

The control works and to keep the session alive, when the button is clicked a `__doPostBack()` is performed.

Although the `__doPostBack()` does the job, it appears to me that there must be a more elegant solution.

I have tried updating an image on the page using the following code which is supposed to work but doesn't, the image gets refreshed but the session doesn't.

```
var myImg = document.getElementById("keepalive");

if (myImg) myImg.src = myImg.src.replace(/\?.*$/, '?' + Math.random());
```

Does anyone know of an elegant solution, perhaps long the lines of a working version of the above?

Comment: images aren't handled by the asp.net handler.  Try pinging a .aspx page that requires session state.  You can make an empty one for this, so the whole lifecycle of another page doesn't have to be calculated for each hit.

Comment: @ps2goat, I'd upvote that as a valid answer, not a mere comment. Now that you beat me to it... [further reading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yedba920%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: if you want to say i'm alive from client to server, you have to make a postback. or call server side method. the javascript function and dom manipulation is a client side and browser dosent send signal to server. use postback button or ajax call

Comment: @Alexander, Moved my comment into an official answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Images aren't handled by the asp.net handler. Try pinging a .aspx page that requires session state. You can make an empty one for this, so the whole lifecycle of another page doesn't have to be calculated for each hit.

Moved the comment from the question to an answer.